# Basic MySQL Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to return the full names of everybody who's last name starts with M-Z. Uppercase is the correct case.

```
Select full_name
from customer
where lastname like '[M-Z]%'
order by lastname;
```

There is something wrong with my syntax on the third like and I cant figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with regular expression.

```
Select full_name from customer where lastname REGEXP '^[M-Z]' order by lastname;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the use of BETWEEN.

```
SELECT full_name
FROM customer
WHERE lastname BETWEEN 'M%' AND 'Z%'
ORDER BY lastname;
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
select full_name from customer where substring(lastname,1,1) >= 'M' and substring(lastname,1,1) <='Z' order by lastname;
```

or

```
select full_name from customer where substring(lastname,1,1) between 'M' and 'Z' order by lastname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code would work as well:

```sql
SELECT fullname FROM customer
WHERE lastname BETWEEN (
    SELECT lastname FROM customer 
    WHERE lastname LIKE 'M%' ORDER BY lastname  ASC LIMIT 1) 
AND (
    SELECT lastname FROM customer 
    WHERE lastname LIKE 'Z%' ORDER BY lastname DESC LIMIT 1
);
```